# Create/Add Foreign Key Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys

I have two tables: Players and GameLog as follows

Players has (Player_ID, FirstName, LastName, Position)

GameLog has (FirstName, LastName, Pts, Date_Played)

I'm afraid the design was a bit poor, but I would like to now link these two tables, so I want to add Player_ID to GameLog and make it a Foreign Key to the Players table.

Is there a way to do this if I already have data in both tables?

So if Players has:

```
Player_ID, FirstName, LastName, Position
1, Kevin, Love, PF
```

And GameLog has:

```
FirstName, LastName, Pts, Date_Played
Kevin, Love, 24, 2/25/2014
```

I want GameLog to become:

```
Player_ID, FirstName, LastName, Pts, Date_Played
1, Kevin, Love, 24, 2/25/2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

THare are two ways to accompiish this.

First, you can add hte field, allow nulls, and then set it up to populate it moving forward.

Then from there, write a match (perhaps on name) that allows you to populate hte rows you can be sure of.

You can apply the FK right away becuase null does not have to have a corresponding record.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you. This plus an UPDATE query did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The result you show suggests a query, such as:

```
SELECT players.Player_ID, players.FirstName, 
       players.LastName, gamelog.Pts, gamelog.Date_Played
FROM gamelog INNER JOIN players ON (gamelog.LastName = players.LastName) 
       AND (gamelog.FirstName = players.FirstName)
```

However, you would be much better off creating a new table:

```
SELECT players.Player_ID, gamelog.Pts, gamelog.Date_Played 
     INTO gamelog2
FROM gamelog INNER JOIN players ON (gamelog.LastName = players.LastName) 
     AND (gamelog.FirstName = players.FirstName);
```

This would allow you to check the new table, and then substitute it for gamelog. There is no reason why gamelog should hold names from the players table when it has a foreign key, ID. You might like to rename ID to PlayerID and add an autonumber to gamelog.